# Read information from a dictionary

Tags: c#

How can I read information from a dictionary to a text box?

```
var cities = new Dictionary<int, string>
{
    { 10, "New York" },
};

textBox1.Text = cities.Values[1];
```

Comment: You can access the value using the key, which is in your case 10 so something like  textBox1.Text = cities[10];

Comment: just in case if you want use it like a list or an array you can do it like this cities[cities.Keys.ElementAt(0)] but then using a dictionary is pointless.

Comment: dictionary works on key value. Use key to retrieve values.

Comment: Key `1` does not exist. You defined key `10`, thus use `textBox1.Text = cities.Values[10];` or a loop or Linq First or Last or anything you want. Or a list box to show all items using for example Format event...

Answer (score 1):

Try instead to use the index that you created on the dictionary:

```
var cities = new Dictionary<int, string>
{
    { 10, "New York" },
};

textBox1.Text = cities[10];
```

Comment: 1 or 10........?

Comment: Dictionaried use keys not indices

Comment: @LeeTaylor it's 10, sorry for the mistake

Comment: @FraguoHoussam - You're looking for the word "key", not "index".

Comment: @ŇɏssaPøngjǣrdenlarp what's the difference between keys and indices ?

Comment: in the above example key is 10 while index is 0

Comment: An index, in computer science, is an integer offset in a collection of elements of the same type - typically an array or a list. It is used to mathematically compute the address of each element. For example, if integers take fours bytes then to determine the third item in a zero-based array you'd compute `base_address + 4 * 2` where `2` is the index. It's a simple computation. A key, on the other hand, as far as dictionaries go, is used to look up a location that the value is in by computing a hash of the key and then finding that hash's location and then finding the value.

Comment: So, we're suggesting that you change the phrase "Try instead to use the ***index*** that you created on the dictionary" to be "Try instead to use the ***key*** that you created on the dictionary".

Comment: @FraguoHoussam - Will you be updating your answer?

Comment: @Enigmativity I'm not really okey with your explanation ! can you please share relevant msdn documentation regarding the context? that would be helpful, thanks !